# RangeFinder class

Tags: python, interval

Can anyone suggest any improvements to this `RangeFinder` class?

```
import serial
from collections import deque

def str2int(x):
    try: 
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass


class RangeFinder(object):

    def __init__(self, mem=3) :
        self.mem = deque(maxlen=mem)
        self.absmax = -10**10
        self.absmin = 10**10
        self.relmax = None
        self.relmin = None

    def __call__(self, input) :
        try:
            self.mem.append(input)
            if len(self.mem) == self.mem.maxlen :       
                self.relmax = max(self.mem)
                if self.relmax > self.absmax :
                    self.absmax = max(self.mem)                   
                self.relmin = min(self.mem) 
                if self.relmin < self.absmin :
                    self.absmin = self.relmin
        except TypeError:
            pass



dev  = '/dev/tty.usbserial-A60085VG'
baud = 9600
serial_reader = serial.Serial(dev,baud)
rf = RangeFinder(5)


for data in serial_reader:
    rf(str2int(data))
    print( rf.mem )
```

I have printed the output of the short term memory used to give a relative max / min and test for absolute max and min:

> ```
> sh > python3 serial_helper2.py 
> deque([877], maxlen=5)
> deque([877, 877], maxlen=5)
> deque([877, 877, 877], maxlen=5)
> deque([877, 877, 877, 877], maxlen=5)
> deque([877, 877, 877, 877, 877], maxlen=5)
> deque([877, 877, 877, 877, 877], maxlen=5)
> deque([877, 877, 877, 877, 877], maxlen=5)
> deque([877, 877, 877, 877, 876], maxlen=5)
> deque([877, 877, 877, 876, 876], maxlen=5)
> deque([877, 877, 876, 876, 876], maxlen=5)
> deque([877, 876, 876, 876, 875], maxlen=5)
> deque([876, 876, 876, 875, 875], maxlen=5)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import serial
from collections import deque

def str2int(x):
    try: 
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

returning `None` is rarely more useful then throwing the exception. Learn to love exceptions, and don't write functions like this that just turn them into `None`

```
class RangeFinder(object):

    def __init__(self, mem=3) :
        self.mem = deque(maxlen=mem)
        self.absmax = -10**10
        self.absmin = 10**10
        self.relmax = None
        self.relmin = None

    def __call__(self, input) :
```

callable objects are rarely the right thing. Its usually clearer to just use a regular method

```
        try:
            self.mem.append(input)
```

So you pass None in here and then stick in on the queue. That doesn't seem like a good idea. Probably, you should avoid calling this when the data was invalid

```
            if len(self.mem) == self.mem.maxlen :       
                self.relmax = max(self.mem)
                if self.relmax > self.absmax :
                    self.absmax = max(self.mem)
```

You can write this as `self.absmax = max(self.absmax, self.relmax)`

```
                self.relmin = min(self.mem) 
                if self.relmin < self.absmin :
                    self.absmin = self.relmin
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

Presumably you've done this to handle the None that you introduced because you used str2int. See how you only made things worse? Because a lot of things in Python throw TypeError, this is a really bad idea because you could catch a lot of errors you didn't mean to catch.

Here's how I would structure your main loop to handle the invalid data

```
for data in serial_reader:
    try:
        value = int(data)
    except ValueError:
        pass # ignore invalid data
    else:
        rf(value)
```

Comment: I have been re-writing it and am trying out just using `if input != None:` which gets me out of using the `try / except` condition. - and also stops None going into the queue. (im also thinking about using deques (maxlen=2) for the min/max. To be honest I don't know how to `handle exceptions` - all I need is for it to keep running - which is why I thought letting it pass (and handling any `None`'s when they came along) would be the easiest.

Comment: @user969617, I've added a bit at the end to show how I'd handle the reading loop.